# Cartthrob multi-add-to-cart not reducing inventory on

Tags: matrix, cartthrob

I have set up CT to use a Matrix for pricing on products. Everything is adding to cart and checkout is OK. I have allow_user_price on as it is a multi-lingual site and I need to show different prices.

No matter what I tweak, I can't get the inventory to reduce once a sale as gone through.

In my Matrix field I have the following:

- option_value
- inventory
- uk_price
- eu_price
- us_price

I have also mapped inventory in to the name of he matrix field in products (pricing).

The multi_add_to_cart is wrapped round a bunch of products. When a customer clicks on more details, Jquery fetches the options - An EE template that loops through options.

Here is a highlight of the options:

```
{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{segment_6}" field="pricing"}
{options}
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{segment_6}{count}]" value="{segment_6}"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_options[{segment_6}{count}][option_value]" value="{option_value}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_options[{segment_6}{count}][size]" value="{size}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_options[{segment_6}{count}][pack]" value="{pack}"/>
<input type="text" id="cart-qty" name="quantity[{segment_6}{count}]" value="">

<button type="submit"  class="add_to_cart_submit btn btn-danger btn-small" >{phrase:add_to_cart}</button>
{/options}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
```

I have omitted the price field and other styling for clarity.

Can anyone see if I am missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 1):

It needs to reference the name of the field. option_value isn't the name of the field (I'd guess). So if your matrix field was called YOUR_FIELD_NAME_HERE, you'd add that as the option name. See example below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_options[{segment_6}{count}][YOUR_FIELD_NAME_HERE]" value="{option_value}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yeah, I got that from the docs. It is as labeled above.<br><br>The matrix table is called 'pricing' and the unique value for that row is called 'sku' with the short name of 'option_value'. <br><br>I've played with renaming this and it hasn't worked.

Comment: For reference based on your feedback it should be thus: <input type="hidden" name="item_options[{segment_6}{count}][pricing]" value="{option_value}"/>

Since you've suggested doesn't seem to work for you, I suggest you schedule a Phone/Skype appointment with the CartThrob/Mightybigrobot support team at http://support.mightybigrobot.com. A member of our support team can speak with your personally and will custom tailor a suitable solution to this issue.